# load PHP: file_get_contents after html loads

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to change working site to load the php `file_get_contents` after the html fully loads. The existing code works fine but due to the large amount of data captured from 3 different sites, its a long delay that sometimes times out the page - I don't want to extend the timeout as others have suggested, I just need to content to load in background after the html loads - other problem may be that index.php (main HTML Page) is a single page with collapsable divs containing the file data.

```
<a href="#hx" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">MC CHATS ()<span class="badge">7</span></a>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="hx" class="collapse">
                    <h1>MC CHATS</h1>
                        <h3>Region V (Hospitals)</h2>
                    <div class="list-group">

<?php
session_start();

$use_sts = true;

if ($use_sts && isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') {
    header('Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000');
} elseif ($use_sts) {
    header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], true, 301);
die();
}

$data = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/region5.php');
$json = json_decode($data, true);
$selected = array(5,6,7,10,12,15,17,18,22,23);
    //$selected = array();

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $selected) || empty($selected)) {
        echo '<a href="#hx" class="list-group-item clearfix" data-toggle="collapse">' . $value["name"] . '<br>'; 
        $length = count($value["color"]);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            if($value['time'][$i] != "") {
                echo '<span class="badge pull-left" style="' . $value["color"][$i] . '">' . $value["time"][$i] . '</span>'; 
            }
        }
        echo '</a>';
    }
}

$data = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/region124.php');
$json = json_decode($data, true);
$selected = array(2);

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $selected) || empty($selected)) {
        echo '<a href="#hx" class="list-group-item clearfix" data-toggle="collapse">' . $value["name"] . '<br>'; 
        $length = count($value["color"]);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            if($value['time'][$i] != "") {
                echo '<span class="badge pull-left" style="' . $value["color"][$i] . '">' . $value["time"][$i] . '</span>'; 
            }
        }
        echo '</a>';
    }
}


$data = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/region3.php');
$json = json_decode($data, true);
$selected = array(3,9,16);

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $selected) || empty($selected)) {
        echo '<a href="#hx" class="list-group-item clearfix" data-toggle="collapse">' . $value["name"] . '<br>'; 
        $length = count($value["color"]);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            if($value['time'][$i] != "") {
                echo '<span class="badge pull-left" style="' . $value["color"][$i] . '">' . $value["time"][$i] . '</span>'; 
                if($value["color"][$i] = "background-color:#ff6600;color:#000000;"){
                }

            }
        }
        echo '</a>';
    }
}

$data = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/region_blue.php');
$json = json_decode($data, true);
$selected = array(2);

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $selected) || empty($selected)) {
        //echo '<br><a href="#hx" class="list-group-item clearfix" data-toggle="collapse">' . $value["name"] . ' (Current Condition Color/Status)<br>'; 
        $length = count($value["color"]);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            if($value['time'][$i] != "") {
                echo '<br><a href="#hx" class="list-group-item clearfix" data-toggle="collapse">' . $value["name"] . ' (Current Condition Color/Status)<br>'; 
                echo '<span class="badge pull-left" style="' . $value["color"][$i] . '">' . $value["time"][$i] . '</span>'; 
            }
        }
        echo '</a>';
    }
}


function myArray($arry) {
    $selected = array(5,6,7,10,12,15,17,18,22,24);
    $color = $time = $emailbody = ""; // <== initialising with empty strings
    foreach($arry as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key, $selected) || empty($selected)) {
            $color .= $value['name']. chr(10);
            $time .= $value['name']. chr(10);
            $emailbody .= $value['name']. '<br>';
            $length = count($value["color"]);
            /*
            // TEST of color alert
            print($color + '<br>' + chr(10) + '<br>');
            print($time + '<br>');
            print($emailbody + '<br>');
            print($length + '<br>');
            // end
            */
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                if($value['time'][$i] != "") {      

                    if(preg_match('/#ff0000/', $value['color'][$i])) {
                        $value['color'][$i] = '<font color="#ff0000">RED</font>';
                    }
                    if(preg_match('/#ffff00/', $value['color'][$i])) {
                        $value['color'][$i] = '<font color="#ffff00">YELLOW</font>';
                    }
                    if(preg_match('/#006600/', $value['color'][$i])) {
                        $value['color'][$i] = '<font color="#006600">GREEN (Mini Disaster)</font>';
                    }
                    if(preg_match('/#9933cc/', $value['color'][$i])) {
                        $value['color'][$i] = '<font color="#9933cc">PURPLE (Trauma ByPass)</font>';
                    }
                    if(preg_match('/#ff6600/', $value['color'][$i])) {
                        $value['color'][$i] = '<font color="#ff6600">ORANGE (ReRoute)</font>';
                    }

                    $time .= '  <b>' . $value["color"][$i] . '</b> - <i>' . $value["time"][$i] . '</i>' . chr(10); 
                    $color .= '  <b>' . $value["color"][$i] . '</b>' . chr(10); 
                    $emailbody .= '  <b>' . $value["color"][$i] . '</b> - <i>' . $value["time"][$i] . '</i><br>';

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return array($time, $color, $emailbody);
}

?>

</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you could use Ajax to load the content. Then it will be loaded in the background using javascript. you can also make three requests at the same time.

Comment: why do you not use ajax ?
and remember sometime on local it takes more time more than server

Comment: I'm not using Ajax because I screen scraping using the server side php page that the data is derived from

Comment: @BarclayVision The purpose of AJAX is to update the page asynchronously. It doesn't matter what method you ultimately use to retrieve the data (screen scraping, retrieving from DB, etc.). Either way, the server retrieves the data and passes it back to JS, which updates the screen.

Comment: so even though my php is doing the screen scraping on the server side, i should use ajax call to my php to get the data... wouldn't the delay i'm experiencing be the same? or would this allow the page to load while the ajax is getting data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single anwser to your question.

1) If the page is rendering it's content using Javascript or some client side processing, you're going to have to use a web driver like Puppeteer, Selenium, Symfony's BrowserKit or any other. It seems that's the problem you're facing

Resources:

- https://github.com/nesk/puphpeteer
- https://symfony.com/components/BrowserKit
- https://www.selenium.dev/

2) If it's just a connetivity issue(which i dont believe) then you can use guzzle instead of file_get_contents for that, since you can validate if the request has been fully executed, response code,etc and with file_get_contents you cant, since the function handles the input as a stream of data.

Something like this:

```php
$client = new Client;
$request = $client->get('www.website.com')

// do your validations
$content = $request->getBody()->getContents();
```

- http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Comment: I'm doing a screen scraping call using php server side and the three different sites are large content retrieved. Would guzzle work with that?

Comment: the php page is also converting the content to json

Comment: Yep, It Will work. I've used to scrap 500 pages with 20 links on each page and It worked just fine.

Comment: so even though my php is doing the screen scraping on the server side, i should use ajax call to my php to get the data... wouldn't the delay i'm experiencing be the same? or would this allow the page to load while the ajax is getting data?

Comment: The delay you're having it will probably be bigger if you do client side processing. In your question you've said: "Get content after html is fully loaded". If the page you're scraping does server side processing only, so you should be able to get the whole content into your response, regardless it's taking a while or not. But if you're not getting the full content, it means the page is rendering it's content using a client side processing technology, so you wont be able to do that using file_get_contents, guzzle or curl, you'll have to use a webdriver or something like that.